Corrosion Concerns on Straight Valves Replacing Kitchen Faucet
I'm looking at replacing a kitchen faucet for my mom since she bought a replacement that's just been sitting around for months.
These are the existing supply line connections:


And the new faucet supply lines:

I'd like to replace the existing hard metal supply lines completely because the connections under the sink are messy, and so are the connections to the existing valves, but the hoses from the faucet seem like they might be just a half inch to short. Was even considering replacing the valves cause they seem compression fitted to the pipes and not soldered.
My main question is about the corrosion/mineral buildup on the threads of the first two photos. If I disconnect either of them will they no longer seal correctly with the new attachment?
If I do replace the entire existing hard metal supply line downstream from the valves how would I even attach the faucet hose since both hose and valve have existing female compression nuts? Or is the 3/8 inch nut on the valve supposed to come off with that hard metal line?
It's really unclear to me where the female compression but of the new faucet's hoses are supposed to connect.

Good news, it is not corrosion, it is a clack build up from a small drip leak. Spray with vinegar and let it work for a while the just wipe off

Let's start at the bottom with those valves and work out way up.
As long as the valves are operable there's no real need to replace them. The way you know is by shutting them down. If they leak or seep after closing them you should replace them. I like the 1/4 turn washerless valves. They are much easier to operate and they're reliable. If they do leak you'll need to turn off the water at the main shutoff.
Compression fittings are also very reliable but if you feel better sweating a valve on, go for it.
Most water supply lines are 3/8" at the valve end and 1/2" FIP at the faucet end. The existing valve looks to be a 3/8". You'll want to clean up the hard water deposits on the existing valve. Vinegar usually does a good job.
Water supply lines come in different lengths, so if those supplied by the manufacturer are too short, you'll have to purchase the appropriate size.
There's no need to clean up the deposits at the top of the supply line since you'll be replacing them. You don't show the attachments from the faucet but the 1/2" supply line should fit it. Some manufacturers supply quick release/snap-on fittings. Again the 1/2" supply line should fit it. If not, simply purchase the correct size.

Even if the valves have some leak-through, there may be a repair kit available—basically includes the valve stem and seals.
